# Appcenter Codepush integration. Cannot add task 'bundleDebugJsAndAssets' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-app-center, code-push, react-native-code-push

## Steps to Reproduce

1. `yarn add react-native-codepush`
2. Add following to `android/app/build.gradle`

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"
```

3. Add following to `MainApplication.java`

```java
...
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;
...
        @Override
        protected String getJSBundleFile() {
            return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
        }
```

4. Add the following to `strings.xml`

```
    <string name="CodePushDeploymentKey" moduleConfig="true">MYKEY</string>
```

## Expected Behavior

Build should be successful

## Actual Behavior

What actually happens?

```
 $ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 998 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app
WARNING: BuildType(debug): resValue 'react_native_dev_server_port' value is being replaced: 8081 -> 8081
WARNING: BuildType(debug): resValue 'react_native_inspector_proxy_port' value is being replaced: 8081 -> 8081
WARNING: BuildType(release): resValue 'react_native_dev_server_port' value is being replaced: 8081 -> 8081
WARNING: BuildType(release): resValue 'react_native_inspector_proxy_port' value is being replaced: 8081 -> 8081

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle' line: 118

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot add task 'bundleDebugJsAndAssets' as a task with that name already exists.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle' line: 118

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot add task 'bundleDebugJsAndAssets' as a task with that name already exists.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

    at makeError (/Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

## Environment

- react-native-code-push version: ^6.2.1
- react-native version: 0.62.2
- iOS/Android/Windows version: unknown
- Does this reproduce on a debug build or release build? only checked on debug
- Does this reproduce on a simulator, or only on a physical device? build error

## External SDKs

I do have an external SDK in `build.gradle`. I don't know if that is the reason for this error.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

....
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

## What I tried.

I moved two declarations to the bottom of `app/build.gradle`. but the error remains same

```
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"
```

Some article state to remove the line `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"`. But New error is

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 998 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-code-push.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-code-push:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-code-push.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-code-push:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

    at makeError (/Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I removed both line (which actually don't make any sense) the error is

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 998 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-code-push.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-code-push:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-code-push.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-code-push:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

    at makeError (/Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/user/Desktop/project/app/native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: And yes I tried gradle clean many times.

Comment: it is head to say where is actual issue. can you add reproducible git repo so I can fix the bug for you

Comment: Did you try to run the cli with --verbose flag for more details?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There were actually two mistakes:

1. There is actually a line present in `android/app/build.gradle` which is `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"`. You don't need to add this line instead you need to add `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"` below it. Adding this at end can solve problem for some user but not for all. Add it at appropriate place.
2. If there is an gradle error it is due to multidex. Enable multidex for all support. Add `multiDexEnable true` in `android` > `defaultConfig`. See this for refrence https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle

Answer (score 15):

I faced the same issue too.

```
"react-native-code-push": "^6.2.1",
"react-native": "0.61.4",
```

Finally, I deleted that line you said and it built successfully.
I placed to the bottom of `build.gradle`

```
apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
//apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually the error is because of unclear documentation . We are supposed to only add
**apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"**
beneath the
**apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle".**
But if we copy the code sample it adds the react.gradle plugin again causing the duplicate gradle task error[image: Code Sample on code push site]

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue, and will outline here for anyone that has the same as me.  Turns out I didn't follow the directions exactly.

It also gave me this error:

```
cannot find symbol
        new CodePush(getResources().getString(R.string.CodePushDeploymentKey), getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.DEBUG)
```

I was using [multi-deployment-testing-android.md](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/multi-deployment-testing-android.md) to use the staging and production keys.  I was confused by the part which said to add your keys to the `android/app/build.gradle` file under `buildTypes`.  Upon opening this file, only `release` was already there, so I only added the `releaseStaging` section.  Turns out you have to also add `debug` as well even if it weren't already there.  Solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

apply from: `"../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` defined before
so simply its a duplication , try to comment or remove it and you ready to go